# Is there a limit to the number of consumers of an eventhub?

Tags: azure-eventhub

I know that the maximum number of ConsumerGroups we can have in an eventhub is 20, and the maximum number of partitions is 32. And with EventProcessorHost, there is only one active reader per ConsumerGroup per partition. So I wanted to know what is the maximum number of consumers reading simultaneously from an eventhub is possible.

Comment: It really depends of your point of view. a reader configured for a specific consumer group is actual looking at the same data as any other reader configured for an other one. But they can all have different positions in the stream of data. Why are you asking this question? You doubt you can read fast enough? or is this just a theoretical question?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I wanted to double check how fast I can read and how many active readers could be at one time. More theoretical.

Comment: Well, that would be 32 readers to read all 32 partitions in the most efficient way (more will just add time to wait for expired leases of a partition). Since a consumer group is just a different view over the same data I would not take that in the calculation. Though AFAIK you can get a higher partition count by reaching out to support.

Comment: Oh! That makes sense! I was initially thinking of including consumer groups in the calculation, in which case I thought I could have up to 32*20 = 640 active readers. Are you saying that we can have 1 reader per partition at a time even if we have 20 consumer groups (so consumer groups really don't matter)?

Comment: No, you are correct in your calculation, but a consumer group reads the same data of the same partition. Say we have a group A and B and one partition. A reader for group A reads the same data as a reader for B, but both can have there own pace as "progression" is stored on a paritionnumber and groupname basis.

Comment: Oh ok! Thanks a lot! That was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

It is recommended to have a maximum of one consumer(belonging to one consumer group) processing events from one partition at one time. However, the Event Hub service supports a maximum of 5 consumers per consumer group concurrently receiving events from one partition. But obviously, since they are subscribed to the same partition and belong to same consumer group, they would be reading in the same data until each consumer maintains and reads from a different offset.
You can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features) article from Azure docs to confirm this.

Also [this blog](http://winterttr.me/2015/09/05/Concurrent-Reader-on-a-specific-EventHub-Partition-within-one-consumer-group/) presents a nice code snippet to test out the same support of up-to 5 concurrent consumers per partition.

So for your figures, I think, theoretically, that would make => 20(consumer groups) *5(consumers per group) *32(partitions) = 3200 active consumer running concurrently.